# Shell seems to recognize commands but doesn't execute them

Tags: c, linux, shell, operating-system, xv6

I am trying to implement basic command execution in a shell program for the unix-like xv6 OS. The part of the shell code that I am editing is the runcmd function where I am using the execvp command to execute the commands used in the terminal. The program compiles without errors when I compile it but nothing happens when I try to type a command on the command line. I've read the [man pages](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/exec.3.html) for the exec command, but I still don't really understand the proper way in which these arguments need to passed in the exec() command or when to use which version of exec() as I'm still very new to OS programming.

What haven't I implemented here that needs to be added in order for commands to be executed? I have the code for the runcmd function below:

### EDIT:

I just added more exec statements with the paths to the binary for each command; however, only the first exec command works (which is cd in this case). When I use any other command, the command line executes it as if it is CD. How do I get it to work for multiple commands?

```
struct cmd {
  int type;          //  ' ' (exec), | (pipe), '<' or '>' for redirection
};
struct
 execcmd {
  int type;              // ' '
  char *argv[MAXARGS];   // arguments to the command to be exec-ed
};

// Execute cmd.  Never returns.
void
runcmd(struct cmd *cmd)
{
  int p[2], r;
  struct execcmd *ecmd;
  struct pipecmd *pcmd;
  struct redircmd *rcmd;

  if(cmd == 0)
    exit(0);
  
  switch(cmd->type){
  default:
    fprintf(stderr, "unknown runcmd\n");
    exit(-1);

  case ' ':
    ecmd = (struct execcmd*)cmd;
    
    if(ecmd->argv[0] == 0)
      exit(0);
    //fprintf(stderr, "exec not implemented\n");
     execvp("/bin/cd" , ecmd->argv );
     execvp("/bin/grep" , ecmd->argv );
     execvp("/bin/echo" , ecmd->argv );
     execvp("/bin/cat" , ecmd->argv );
     execvp("/bin/ls" , ecmd->argv );
    break;

  case '>':
  case '<':
    rcmd = (struct redircmd*)cmd;
    //fprintf(stderr, "redir not implemented\n");
    execvp("/bin" , ecmd->argv );
    runcmd(rcmd->cmd);
    break;

  case '|':
    pcmd = (struct pipecmd*)cmd;
    fprintf(stderr, "pipe not implemented\n");
    int execl(const char *path, const char *arg, ...);
    break;
  }    
  exit(0);
}
```

Comment: Well and just for starters, `int execl(const char *path, const char *arg, ...);` *declares* the function `execl`, it doesn't *call* it.  Does this "xv6" operating system have `<unistd.h>`?

Comment: @zwol yes it has <unistd.h> and I hadn't replaced that line yet, because I thought that I could just wait until I had to implement piping.

Comment: Re your modification to the question, the `exec` family of functions only return when they have failed; you need a `fork` in there somewhere.  Also, `cd` is one of the special commands that *must* be implemented as a shell built-in, not as an external executable; I would expect `/bin/cd` not to exist.

Comment: Re `execl`, you're right, it's not doing any *harm*, I was reading the wrong part of the code.  Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: You may find this documentation helpful: https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Processes.html , https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Job-Control.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I *think* this is what you actually need:

```
case ' ':
    ecmd = (struct execcmd*)cmd;
    if (ecmd->argv[0] == 0)
        _exit(0);
    execvp(ecmd->argv[0], ecmd->argv);
    /* if control reaches this point, execvp failed */
    perror(ecmd->argv[0]);
    _exit(127);
```

You may be wondering why `execvp` takes the executable to load as a separate argument from the argument vector, when you're just going to hand it `argv[0]`.  This is legacy functionality; if I were designing this API from scratch today, I don't think I would include it.  However, the idea is that a program might behave differently depending on what its `argv[0]` is.  For instance, back in the day `ex` and `vi` were the *same executable* (two hard links to the same inode -- symlinks had not been invented yet), which decided what mode to start up in based on its `argv[0]`.  And, since the dawn of Unix, [`login(1)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/login.1.html) has [invoked shells with the first character of `argv[0]` set to `'-'`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/bash.1.html#INVOCATION); there is no `/bin/-sh`, so it actually *needs* the ability to specify the program-to-invoke separately from the argument vector.

I can't presently think of a situation where a *shell* would use anything other than `argv[0]` as the first argument to `execvp`.

Notes on other changes to your code:

- Never call `exit` on the child side of a `fork`, only `_exit`.
- When a system call fails, **always** print out both the name of the offending file and `strerror(errno)`, to `stderr`, **not** `stdout`. `perror` is a convenient shorthand for this operation.
- For the `perror` call to be safe, you must have called `fflush(0)` in the parent, *immediately* before the `fork`, and your C library must implement line-buffering of stderr, correctly.  I mention this because XV6 appears to be a teaching OS where you have to implement bits of it yourself, and I don't know whether stdio is your responsibility or not.

Comment: Thanks, this was a very clear and understandable answer! And yes I was confused about why the ecmd->argv had to be taken as another argument. So you're basically saying that its standard to use the first element of the argv array in most cases except some like login where I'm assuming additional indices will be needed?

Comment: @loremIpsum1771 Right.  I'll expand on that a little in the body of the answer, since you're curious.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you are trying to execute the "/bin" directory.

You should make the first argument to the exec call be the binary the user wants to run.

Using the perror function would also give you useful output when the command fails.

Comment: By "the binary" do you mean the path to the file location for each  command?  If so, wouldn't that make it so that it only executes the command located in that one location? How would I make it so that it can execute any command (e.g. ls, grep, cat, etc ...).